# How do I update a subscription?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

Doesn't seem to be a way to:

1. Update a subscription on the front end or
2. Update a subscription in the CP.

Am I missing something?

I'm in "Test" mode, and using EE 2.7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control panel for individual subscriptions is set to be released soon and will be updated at no additional cost.

Comment: Two years on I could really use this facility but it still doesn't seem to be possible - am I missing something? The ability for administrators to manage subs in the CP is something that I would have thought would be a must? I need to create some subscribers that have paid offline but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it unless I'm missing something!